# Static layout, but content is derived from different files

Tags: asp.net, webforms, master-pages

In my website I have (for the sake of the example) 3 divs.
the layout always stays the same, but the content of each div is derived every time from a different file.

as you can see in the picture below: (every small square is a different file)
[image: My basic layout]

so, in my first div there could be one of three possible files: red.html, yellow.html, and green.html.

and so on for the rest of the divs accordingly.

How can I create this layout, without having to copy the entire code for all possible combinations?

failed attempt:
I tried to use a masterpage, but in a master page, some content always stays static.
in my example, all the content on the page changes, with no regards to the other divs.

How can I create a layout to which I can just say:

```
for div1 use yellow.html
for div2 use orange.html
and for div 3 use grey.html
```

If I fail to explain myself fully, please drop a comment and i'll edit the post.

I am really struggling here :\

Thanks everyone!

**EDIT:**

I'll add sample code of using masterpages to illustrate my problem

this is my master page. it has 2 divs. one is floated left, and the other is floated right.

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.vb" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="CPHL" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
        <div style="width:50%;float:right;">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="CPHR" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

here is a webform for the left side:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPHL" Runat="Server">
    This is the left side
</asp:Content>
```

here if a webform for my right side:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default2" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPHR" Runat="Server">
    This is the Right side
</asp:Content>
```

if I open the first file, I'll only see the left side, if I open the second file, I'll only see the right side.

obviously, this is not the way to go.

I can instead create a nested masterpage that displays the left side automatically and then have the second file (that displays the right side) to display both sides using the master page but, then I would not be able to change the left side without creating a new master page.

the solution I'm looking for is something like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="CPHL" runat="server">
here I decide which file I want to include

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
        <div style="width:50%;float:right;">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="CPHR" runat="server">
here I decide which file I want to include

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

so it's a strategy of top down instead of bottom up.

so I could say in the main file:
for the left side include anyfile_no312.html

and in the right side include anyfile_no_839.html

and I would be able to change the content of the separate divs independently.

in classic asp I could have a file like this:

```
<div id="container">

        <!--#include file="header.asp"-->

        <div id="main">
                <!--#include file="Story.asp"-->
            <div id="sidebar">
                <!--#include file="quicklinks.asp"-->
                <!--#include file="Menu2.asp"-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <!--#include file="footer.asp"-->
        </div>
```

in this case I can specifically add more menus to a certain page, or remove the footer from a certain page and so on. it allows me to easily edit the content of the page without having to create tons of possibilities.

how can I translate this classic asp example to asp.net working code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap up your colour-coded files in user controls and use content placeholders:

Master page:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="Div1" runat="server">
    <p>Some optional default content</p>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

ASPX page:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="Div1" runat="server">
    <MyPrefix:MyControl runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

To explain further:

You would have one master page with three content placeholders:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="Div1" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="Div2" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="Div3" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Then, you would have a user control for each of your colours. Now, suppose you want Red, Orange and Purple. Create a page that looks like this:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="Div1" runat="server">
    <Colours:Red runat="server" />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="Div2" runat="server">
    <Colours:Orange runat="server" />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="Div3" runat="server">
    <Colours:Purple runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

You can just create pages like the above that have whatever combination of "colours" you need.

Comment: I am using webforms. do you know of a solution that might work for webforms too?

Comment: My mistake - thought you'd mentioned MVC. I've updated my answer with a WebForms solution.

Comment: I get how in masterpages I will be able to dynamically change one file every time, but how can I set all three from one page?

Comment: Wouldn't having three content placeholders achieve this? If not, I think I'm missing something.

Comment: I edited the post, please let me know if my problem is clearer to you.

Comment: I still think content placeholders solve your problem. See my edit.

Comment: this is it!!! wow! thanks! can you briefly explain how to use user controls or refer me to an article on the subject?
this has me going crazy all day!!

Comment: and I use the user control just like any old webform? are there any implication of switching from webforms to user controls apart from being able to reference them in a master page?

Comment: You don't reference the user controls in the master page, you reference them in your content page and put them inside your master page placeholders. Essentially user controls are designed to break up pages into flexible, reusable components, which is exactly what you need. All the normal <asp:Control /> tags (TextBoxes, GridViews...) are user controls - just built-in ones. What you need is to design your own.